# How to Bind Data to Multi-Column ListBox WP8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I'm new to the whole data binding thing with XAML for WP8.1. I've been searching on the internet and I can't seem to find a straight-forward answer to my problem.

I have a ListBox control on my page with 3 columns. What I need to do is fill each column with it's respective data.

I have a class that defines a "CompleteStation" which is made up of 3 strings (StationName, Distance, and GasPrice)

This is the XAML code for the ListBox... How am I able to pass the ListBox a CompleteStation (3 strings) and have it separate each string into the correct column?

This is my XAML code below. In my main class, I'm just adding a CommpleteStation item to the ListBox.

Also, do I need to reference the CompleteStation class in the XAML code? If yes, how do I do this?

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxStations" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="480" Background="#e6e6e6" Margin="0,10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Station}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Distance}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Thanks!

-Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your **CompleteStation** is an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which implements [`NotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), Then XAML should be as follows

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxStations" ItemSource={Binding CompleteStation} FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="480" Background="#e6e6e6" Margin="0,10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Station}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Distance}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Price}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Your Model:

```
public sealed class CommpleteStation
{
  public string Station{get;set;}
  public string Distance{get;set;}
  public string Price{get;set;}
}
```

Your ViewModel:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<CommpleteStation> CommpleteStations{get;private set;}
  public MyViewModel()
  {
    CommpleteStations = new ObservableCollection<CommpleteStation>();
    CommpleteStations.Add(new CommpleteStation{Station="One", Distance="15",Price="130"};
  }
}
```

Then,

IN codebehind for your UI, the "View", you instantiate your ViewModel and set it as the DataContext for your View.

```
public MyView()
{
  this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

Comment: How do I reference the Binding CompleteStation in my XAML code at the top? Don't I need to do that?

Comment: @user3138251 You dont have to do that if you are binding relative

Comment: Sorry about that, I completely forgot! My bad!